# knockout apply foreach binding using script

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I trying to apply binding using script as below code:

```
<div data-bind="custom: {}">
  <div class="list">
    <span data-bind="text: text, click: doSomething"></span>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;
  </div>
</div>

ko.bindingHandlers.custom = {
  init: function (ele) {
    var list = ko.observableArray([]),
        ee = $(ele).find('.list')[0]

    ... code / event / callback / trigger to keep the list data change

    ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.apply(this, ee, list) //this line not work
  }
}
```

which similar like :

```
<div data-bind="custom: {}"> //tested and confirm work
  <div class="list" data-bind="foreach: ko.observableArray([ { id: 'a', text: 'aa' } ])">
    <span data-bind="text: text, click: doSomething"></span>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

my question is what wrong with this

```
ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.apply(this, ee, list)
```

?

try at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SimonYong/sZzYB/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `call` rather than `apply`; `call` takes a context and any number of arguments which are passed to the function, whereas `apply` takes a context and a single array argument, whose elements are passed as arguments to the function.

Comment: thanks for replay but your idea seem not work, i tested in http://jsfiddle.net/SimonYong/sZzYB/, or maybe you can test it out.
anyway thanks for helping